# Displaying flash messages on modal popup cakephp

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flash, cakephp, modal-dialog

I am trying to build the modal box to display the result of Session->setFlush() method in modal popup bootsrap,I have done it but can not able to find the way to display the flash messages on modal dialog box when registration done.
This is my function controller code:

```
    public function inscriptioncompte(){

    $this->Session->setFlash("Verifier votre boite mail afin de valider votre inscription.",'ok');
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $posted_data = $this->request->data;
        $interet = rtrim($interet, ";");
        $this->User->create();
        $this->User->set(array(
            'username'=>$posted_data['User']['username'],
            'password'=>$posted_data['User']['password'],
            'group_id'=>3));


        $datenaissance = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($posted_data['User']['datenaissance']));
        if($this->User->validates()){
            if($this->User->save()){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Verifier votre boite mail afin de valider votre inscription.",'ok');
                $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash("Une erreur c'est produite lors de votre inscription.",'ko');
                $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
            }
        }else{
            $erreurs = $this->User->invalidFields();
            $erreurToShow = "";
            if(isset($erreurs['username']['0']) && !empty($erreurs['username']['0'])){
                $erreurToShow = $erreurs['username']['0'];
            }
            if(isset($erreurs['password']['0']) && !empty($erreurs['password']['0'])){
                $erreurToShow = $erreurToShow.$erreurs['password']['0'];
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash("Erreur : ".$erreurToShow,'ko');
            $this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the modal code:

```
<div id="printPlaning" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Imprimez votre planing</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <label for="formation_id"> text body</label>
          <div>
            input
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          footer
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

any idea please how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var ins = <?php echo $inscription; ?>;
       if(ins){
        $('#printPlaning').modal('show');
       }

 });
```

$inscription virable is comming when I call my controller